# How to call a function in block in magento from javascript?

Tags: magento

I want to call a function(that sets a session variable) in block of Magento from inside an `if` condition in javascript.

```
if(response.responseJSON.Response=="Success")
  {            
    `enter code here`// call the function to set session variable
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, you need to check section.xml and customerData concepts, is the right way to communicate backend to frontend config or data.

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/112948/magento-2-how-do-customer-sections-sections-xml-work